# How can i pass output parameters using JdbcTemplate.Query?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

i did not have acess to connection object.

I only receive a JdbcTemplate object of my connection factory, but it's all encapsulated.

How can i pass input/output parameters through "jdbctemplate.query" for example?

Any Idea?

i'm using oracle 11g database server.

----UPDATED----

I'm trying to do something like:

The last procedure parameter is an output parameter type... how can i pass this parameter in this situation?

```
final Object[] params = {param1,param2,?}

try{
  jdbcTemplate.update("call package1.procedure (?,?,?)",params);
}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Failure. :" + e.getMessage());
}
```

More one question... i'm trying to execute a store procedure inside a package (oracle 11g). I need to do something especial in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804984/spring-jdbctemplate-stored-procedure-with-resultset-and-output-parameter