# How to succinctly call a PL/SQL procedure and return its output variables in Spring with JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, plsql, jdbctemplate

New to Oracle here.  My experience is building web apps which send queries to a database and get a "result set" back, for example in Java with Spring and JdbcTemplate.

For example, here's a code sample with a regular SQL query, using a `RowMapper` class to turn the rows of a result set into a Java list:

```java
public List<Widget> findAllWidgets() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM widgets", new WidgetRowMapper());
}
```

Now I am tasked with writing a query that calls a PL/SQL stored procedure.  This procedure has two input arguments (these I can handle) and two output arguments (let's call them `error_code` and `error_message`).  I want to send a query to the database that will (a) run the procedure with my inputs and (b) return the two outputs.  I would be equally happy to have the two outputs as a "row" or simply bind them to two Java variables.

Here's what I've tried, and it's not throwing an error but it's not getting the output values, either.  The Java variables `errorCode` and `errorMessage` remain empty strings:

```java
public Map<String,String> callMyProcedure() {
    String errorCode="";
    String errorMessage="";
    jdbcTemplate.update("call myprocedure(?,?,?,?)","input1","input2",errorCode,errorMessage);
    return Map.of("errorCode",errorCode,"errorMessage",errorMessage);
}
```

The question is: **How can I capture the values of the PL/SQL procedure's "OUT" variables when calling the procedure from Java with JdbcTemplate?**

EDIT: I accepted Alex's answer which doesn't use JdbcTemplate, because it seems to be the better way.  My own answer *does* use JdbcTemplate but takes a lot more code, so if you're searching for something that specifically answers the question, that will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain JDBC.

```
final String charlie;
final String zulu;
try (CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call myprocedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}")) {
    cs.setString(1, "foo");
    cs.setString(2, "bar");
    cs.setString(3, "baz");
    cs.setString(4, "whisky");
    cs.setString(5, "tango");
    cs.setString(6, "foxtrot");
    cs.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.execute();
    connection.commit(); // optional
    charlie = cs.getString(7);
    zulu = cs.getString(8);
}
```

When using JDBC, it is dangerous to use the `getInt` method and similar ones, since they convert the type to primitive and zero is replaced by 0. It is better to use a `(Integer) cs.getObject()`. Similarly, `setInt` does not support the reference type.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the connection under `jdbcTemplate` and get output using get methods as [getNString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getNString(java.lang.String))

```
try (Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{call myprocedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
statement.execute();
statement.getNString(1); // using index or your parameter name
```

> Retrieves the value of the designated NCHAR, NVARCHAR or LONGNVARCHAR parameter as a String in the Java programming language.

Comment: It's pure jdbc.

Comment: call `statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NVARCHAR)` is missing

Answer (score 0):

I found some guidance from an [older question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984167/3938965), and came up with this monstrosity:

```java
    public Map<String,Object> callMyProcedure() {
        return jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call myprocedure(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
                cs.setString(1,"foo");
                cs.setString(2,"bar");
                cs.setString(3,"baz");
                cs.setString(4,"whisky");
                cs.setString(5,"tango");
                cs.setString(6,"foxtrot");
                cs.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
                cs.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);
                return cs;
            }
        },Arrays.asList(
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("errorCode",Types.VARCHAR),
                new SqlOutParameter("errorMessage",Types.VARCHAR)
        ));
    }
```

It does *work*, but I'm looking for an answer that can do the same thing more succinctly.  Maybe Spring has added a new interface to JdbcTemplate in the years since that older answer?

Comment: Yes, it's the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48821425. Isn't it easier to use pure jdbc?

Comment: @Alex78191 I don't know where `jdbcTemplate` ends and "pure JDBC" begins, but the main reasons I don't like this answer are that it requires lots of code that provides no information (i.e. re-stating the data types of the input parameters), is hard for a programmer to read, and would be prone to bugs from all the code duplication and copy-pasting needed.  If I could *just* register the output arguments and not all the input arguments, it would go a long way toward more readable, maintainable code.

Comment: Pure jdbc means using `cs.execute` instead of `jdbcTemplate.call`.

Comment: FYU you can set any type in SqlParameter and SqlParameter.

Comment: @Alex78191 Can you add an answer, or link to one, that shows how to do this with pure JDBC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984167/ `1. Using CallableStatement:`